# How to set a background color to a JFrame containing multiple JPanels, JButtons and JLabels?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, colors, jpanel

## The problem

First, I am using Eclipse. So, I'm building a Frame with multiple Panels, Buttons and Labels on it, and I would like to have another color than the default white. I tried several solution, found here on StackOverflow, like these :

- [Setting background color on a jpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966773/set-background-color-in-java-on-a-jpanel-doesnt-work)
- [Use of paintComponent function on a JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446396/concerns-about-the-function-of-jpanel-paintcomponent)
- [Setting background color for the JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081486/setting-background-color-for-the-jframe)

None of the solutions proposed here and there worked for me. Now is time to show a bit of code, in order to understand what I want to do, and if it is possible to do it.

So here is my JFrame class, called `Body.java`. As I am using a lot of classes (extending JPanel, like 15 or so), I commented all the code in `Body` that you can't compile. I just left a small class used on my frame, and I will apply the solution afterwards on each class. You can of course ask me for more classes ! I ran that code, and everything is OK (compilation and execution complete). I left everything so if you get more classes, you can compile this code.

Note that as I'm French, all the classe's names are in French, some comments too (but I translated all the necessary comments to understand what I'm doing, and I added some). What will be displayed will be in French too.

## The code

#### `Simplicity.java` :

it is my controller, just used to launch the Frame

```
package controller;

import view.Body;

public class Simplicity {

    public Simplicity() {
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Body fen = new Body();
        fen.setVisible(true);
        
    }

}
```

Here is the code of the Frame :

#### `Body.java`

```
package view;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

/**
 * @author David Rei
 *
 */

/*
 * This is a project in which we had to develop a UI for smartphones.
 */

public class Body extends JFrame{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    // initial size : width = 230, height = 390.
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 250;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;
    
    // My fixed panels
    private static JPanel niveauBase = new JPanel(); // Basic panel -> everything will go on it
    private static JPanel infosReseauxHeure = new JPanel(); // Panel fixed
    private JPanel panelChangeable = new JPanel(); // Scrolling panel
    
    // up of page info
    private static JTextPane infos = new JTextPane();
    
    // Creation of the different pages (panels)
    private Tutoriel tuto;
    /*
    private Accueil1 ac1;
    private Accueil2 ac2;
    private Medias1 med1;
    private Multimedias1 multimed1;
    private Outils1 out1;
    private Outils2 out2;
    private Jeux1 jeux1;
    private Jeux2 jeux2;
    private SocialInternet1 socInt1;
    private SocialInternet2 socInt2;
    
    private Appeler appeler;
    private Urgences urgences;
    
    private AppelEnCours appelEnCours;
    private DemarrageApp demarrageApp;
    private EnConstruction enConstruction;
    */
    public Body() {
        super();
        buildFrame();
        this.buildContentPane();
        this.setContentPane(niveauBase);
    }
    public void buildFrame() {
        this.setTitle("Simplicity");
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 105, 86));
        
        // toutes les dimensions sont en relatif par rapport à la taille de la JFrame. de fait, en changeant celle-ci, on peut adapter l'interface à différents écrans      
        
        // on met en place ce qui ne changera jamais d'un panel à l'autre --> les infos de base et le support
            // support
        niveauBase.setLayout(null);
        
            // basic info
        infosReseauxHeure.setBounds(0, 0, this.getWidth(), (int)(0.12*this.getHeight()));
        infosReseauxHeure.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        infosReseauxHeure.add(infos);

            // adding the text
        niveauBase.add(infosReseauxHeure);
        
        // defining the limits of the changing Panel, bc they are always the same
        panelChangeable.setLayout(null);
        // My first try of changing the background 
//      panelChangeable.setBackground(new Color(255, 105, 86));
        panelChangeable.setBounds(0, infosReseauxHeure.getHeight(), this.getWidth(), (int) (0.88*this.getHeight()));
        niveauBase.add(panelChangeable);
        
        // the basic frame, which will never change, is ready.
        
    }
    public void buildContentPane() {
        
        // Instantiation of the pages
        
        tuto = new Tutoriel(this);
        /*
        ac1 = new Accueil1(this);
        ac2 = new Accueil2(this);
        med1 = new Medias1(this);
        multimed1 = new Multimedias1(this);
        out1 = new Outils1(this);
        out2 = new Outils2(this);
        jeux1 = new Jeux1(this);
        jeux2 = new Jeux2(this);
        socInt1 = new SocialInternet1(this);
        socInt2 = new SocialInternet2(this);
        
        appeler = new Appeler(this);
        urgences = new Urgences(this);
        
        appelEnCours = new AppelEnCours(this);
        demarrageApp = new DemarrageApp(this);
        enConstruction = new EnConstruction(this);
        */
        
        // Tutoriel is the first to be displayed
        CaractsPanelChangeant(tuto);
        panelChangeable.add(tuto);
        
        // all the other panels have the same displaying characteristics
        // navigating panels
        /*
        addPanels(ac1);
        addPanels(ac2);
        addPanels(med1);
        addPanels(multimed1);
        addPanels(out1);
        addPanels(out2);
        addPanels(jeux1);
        addPanels(jeux2);
        addPanels(socInt1);
        addPanels(socInt2);
        
        // applications panels
        addPanels(appeler);
        addPanels(urgences);
        
        // diverse panels
        addPanels(appelEnCours);
        addPanels(demarrageApp);
        addPanels(enConstruction);
        */
    }
    // fixating the same size and origins for all the panels
    public void CaractsPanelChangeant(JPanel a) {
        
        a.setBounds(0, 0, panelChangeable.getWidth(), panelChangeable.getHeight());
    }
    // regroup the same actions for the panels : bounds, adding and invisible
    public void addPanels(JPanel a) {
        CaractsPanelChangeant(a);
        panelChangeable.add(a);
        a.setVisible(false);
        /*
         * I tried to change the background here too
        a.setOpaque(true);
        a.setBackground(new Color(255, 105, 86));
        */
    }
    
    // JPanel getters
    public static int getInfosReseauxHeureHeight() {
        return infosReseauxHeure.getHeight();
    }
    /*
    public Accueil1 getAc1() {
        return ac1;
    }
    public Accueil2 getAc2() {
        return ac2;
    }
    public Medias1 getMed1() {
        return med1;
    }
    public Multimedias1 getMultimed1() {
        return multimed1;
    }
    public Outils1 getOut1() {
        return out1;
    }
    public Outils2 getOut2() {
        return out2;
    }
    public Jeux1 getJeux1() {
        return jeux1;
    }
    public Jeux2 getJeux2() {
        return jeux2;
    }
    public SocialInternet1 getSocInt1() {
        return socInt1;
    }
    public SocialInternet2 getSocInt2() {
        return socInt2;
    }
    
    public Appeler getAppeler() {
        return appeler;
    }
    public Urgences getUrgences() {
        return urgences;
    }
    public AppelEnCours getAppelEnCours() {
        return appelEnCours;
    }
    public DemarrageApp getDemarrageApp() {
        return demarrageApp;
    }
    public EnConstruction getEnConstruction() {
        return enConstruction;
    }
    */
    public Tutoriel getTuto() {
        return tuto;
    }
    
    // other getters
    public static int getFrameWidth() {
        return FRAME_WIDTH;
    }
    public static int getFrameHeight() {
        return FRAME_HEIGHT;
    }
    public JPanel getPanelChangeable() {
        return panelChangeable;
    }
    
    // setters
    public void setPanelChangeable(JPanel a) {
        this.panelChangeable = a;
    }
    /*
    public void switchAccueil(){
        ac1.setVisible(!ac1.isVisible());
        ac2.setVisible(!ac2.isVisible());
    }
    */
}
```

So this is my JFrame. Here is now the small class I talked previously, which is the tutorial of using our project (comments in `Body.java`, at the beginning).

#### `Tutoriel.java` :

```
package view;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import model.SelectAction;


/**
 * @author David Rei
 *
 */

/*
 * This class displays a tutorial when the application is launched.
 * It is then setVisible(false), to not appear again.
 * Here, I use it to show you one of my panels, which background has to be a color.
 * 
 */
public class Tutoriel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Body body;
    
    // panels
    private JPanel tout;
    private JPanel centre;
    private JPanel messageCentre1;
    private JPanel messageCentre2;
    
    // buttons
    private JButton ok1;
    private JButton ok2;
    
    private JLabel messageHaut;
    private JLabel tuto1;
    private JLabel FGauche;
    private JLabel FDroite;
    private JLabel tuto2;
    private JCheckBox tutoOff;
    
    //private Color fond = new Color(255, 105, 86);


    public Tutoriel(Body body) {
        super();
        this.body = body;
        buildTuto();
    }
    public void buildTuto() {
        
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        tout = new JPanel();
        tout.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));
        this.add(tout);
        
        // tutorial announce
        messageHaut = new JLabel("TUTORIEL");
        messageHaut.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        messageHaut.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
        messageHaut.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        tout.add(messageHaut, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        // central panel, with the tutorial
        centre = new JPanel();
        centre.setLayout(null);
        tout.add(centre, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        // first tutorial
        messageCentre1 = new JPanel();
        messageCentre1.setLayout(null);
        messageCentre1.setBounds(0, 0, 250, 300);
        centre.add(messageCentre1);
        
        tuto1 = new JLabel("<html>POUR NAVIGUER ENTRE<br>LES DIFFÉRENTES PAGES<br>UTILISER LES FLÈCHES</html>");
        tuto1.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        tuto1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        tuto1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        tuto1.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        tuto1.setBounds(20, -10, 200, 150);
        messageCentre1.add(tuto1);
        
        // arrows
        FGauche = new JLabel();
        FGauche.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/left-blue.png")));
        FGauche.setBackground(new Color(255, 153, 0));
        FGauche.setBounds(80, 150, 40, 40);
        messageCentre1.add(FGauche);
        
        FDroite = new JLabel();
        FDroite.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/right-blue.png")));
        FDroite.setBackground(new Color(255, 153, 0));
        FDroite.setBounds(140, 150, 40, 40);
        messageCentre1.add(FDroite);
        
        // OK button, first tutorial
        ok1 = new JButton(new SelectAction(body));
        ok1.setActionCommand("tuto1");
        ok1.setText("OK");
        ok1.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        ok1.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        ok1.setBackground(new Color(255, 153, 0));
        ok1.setBounds(105, 230, 40, 40);
        messageCentre1.add(ok1);
        
        // second tutorial
        messageCentre2 = new JPanel();
        messageCentre2.setLayout(null);
        messageCentre2.setBounds(0, 0, 250, 300);
        centre.add(messageCentre2);
        
        tuto2 = new JLabel("<html>POUR RETOURNER<br>A L'ACCUEIL, APPUYER<br>SUR LA TOUCHE G</html>");
        tuto2.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        tuto2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        tuto2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        tuto2.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        tuto2.setBounds(20, -10, 200, 150);
        messageCentre2.add(tuto2);
        
        // OK button, second tutorial
        ok2 = new JButton(new SelectAction(body));
        ok2.setActionCommand("tuto2");
        ok2.setText("OK");
        ok2.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        ok2.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        ok2.setBackground(new Color(255, 153, 0));
        ok2.setBounds(105, 230, 40, 40);
        messageCentre2.add(ok2);
        
        // visibility of tutorial panels
        //messageCentre1.setVisible(false);
        messageCentre2.setVisible(false);
        
        // deactivate the tutorial (and reach the main page)
        tutoOff = new JCheckBox(new SelectAction(body));
        tutoOff.setActionCommand("tutoOff");
        tutoOff.setText("NE PLUS AFFICHER AU DÉMARRAGE");
        tutoOff.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        tout.add(tutoOff, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
    /*
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(fond);
        g.drawOval(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }
    */
    public JPanel getMessageCentre1() {
        return messageCentre1;
    }
    public JPanel getMessageCentre2() {
        return messageCentre2;
    } 

}
```

## The solution?

I know there is something with `paintComponent`, `paint` but I tried to understand how they work, I tried to implement the solutions in the links above, and I couldn't achieve it.

So, if you're still there, here is what I exactly would like to do : I would like to apply a color on the JPanel `niveauBase`, because everything will be placed on that Panel. So if I can have a color on it, I will not have to apply a color on each panel.

I think I explained everything, but feel free to ask for more explanations or details.

Thank you for your time, dear StackOverflowers !

Comment: *"None of the solutions proposed here and there worked for me."* What happened when you tried them? Please also consider posting a [more minimal but still complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the difficulty you're having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Set the main content pane JPanel's background to whatever color you desire, `Color.BLUE`.
- Make all other JPanels that is displayed in your main GUI non-opaque by calling `setOpaque(false)` on all of them (although I do find it hard that none of "the solutions proposed here" told you this. This will allow the background color of the contentPane to show through.

Also some side recommendations:

- While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

---

For example, some of your code with the blue showing through:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
//!! import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class Simplicity {

    public Simplicity() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Body fen = new Body();
        fen.setVisible(true);

    }

}

class Body extends JFrame{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 250;
   private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;

   private static JPanel niveauBase = new JPanel(); // Basic panel -> everything will go on it
   private static JPanel infosReseauxHeure = new JPanel(); // Panel fixed
   private JPanel panelChangeable = new JPanel(); // Scrolling panel

   // up of page info
   private static JTextPane infos = new JTextPane();

   // Creation of the different pages (panels)
   private Tutoriel tuto;

   public Body() {
       super();
       buildFrame();
       this.buildContentPane();
       this.setContentPane(niveauBase);
   }
   public void buildFrame() {
       this.setTitle("Simplicity");
       this.setResizable(false);
       this.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
       this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 105, 86));

       // toutes les dimensions sont en relatif par rapport à la taille de la JFrame. de fait, en changeant celle-ci, on peut adapter l'interface à différents écrans      

       // on met en place ce qui ne changera jamais d'un panel à l'autre --> les infos de base et le support
           // support
       niveauBase.setLayout(null);
       niveauBase.setBackground(Color.blue); //!!

           // basic info
       infosReseauxHeure.setOpaque(false);
       infosReseauxHeure.setBounds(0, 0, this.getWidth(), (int)(0.12*this.getHeight()));
       infosReseauxHeure.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
       infosReseauxHeure.add(infos);

           // adding the text
       niveauBase.add(infosReseauxHeure);

       // defining the limits of the changing Panel, bc they are always the same
       panelChangeable.setOpaque(false);
       panelChangeable.setLayout(null);
       // My first try of changing the background 
//     panelChangeable.setBackground(new Color(255, 105, 86));
       panelChangeable.setBounds(0, infosReseauxHeure.getHeight(), this.getWidth(), (int) (0.88*this.getHeight()));
       niveauBase.add(panelChangeable);

       // the basic frame, which will never change, is ready.

   }
   public void buildContentPane() {

       // Instantiation of the pages

       tuto = new Tutoriel(this);
       /*
       ac1 = new Accueil1(this);
       ac2 = new Accueil2(this);
       med1 = new Medias1(this);
       multimed1 = new Multimedias1(this);
       out1 = new Outils1(this);
       out2 = new Outils2(this);
       jeux1 = new Jeux1(this);
       jeux2 = new Jeux2(this);
       socInt1 = new SocialInternet1(this);
       socInt2 = new SocialInternet2(this);

       appeler = new Appeler(this);
       urgences = new Urgences(this);

       appelEnCours = new AppelEnCours(this);
       demarrageApp = new DemarrageApp(this);
       enConstruction = new EnConstruction(this);
       */

       // Tutoriel is the first to be displayed
       CaractsPanelChangeant(tuto);
       panelChangeable.add(tuto);

       // all the other panels have the same displaying characteristics
       // navigating panels
       /*
       addPanels(ac1);
       addPanels(ac2);
       addPanels(med1);
       addPanels(multimed1);
       addPanels(out1);
       addPanels(out2);
       addPanels(jeux1);
       addPanels(jeux2);
       addPanels(socInt1);
       addPanels(socInt2);

       // applications panels
       addPanels(appeler);
       addPanels(urgences);

       // diverse panels
       addPanels(appelEnCours);
       addPanels(demarrageApp);
       addPanels(enConstruction);
       */
   }
   // fixating the same size and origins for all the panels
   public void CaractsPanelChangeant(JPanel a) {

       a.setBounds(0, 0, panelChangeable.getWidth(), panelChangeable.getHeight());
   }
   // regroup the same actions for the panels : bounds, adding and invisible
   public void addPanels(JPanel a) {
       CaractsPanelChangeant(a);
       panelChangeable.add(a);
       a.setVisible(false);
       /*
        * I tried to change the background here too
       a.setOpaque(true);
       a.setBackground(new Color(255, 105, 86));
       */
   }

   // JPanel getters
   public static int getInfosReseauxHeureHeight() {
       return infosReseauxHeure.getHeight();
   }
   /*
   public Accueil1 getAc1() {
       return ac1;
   }
   public Accueil2 getAc2() {
       return ac2;
   }
   public Medias1 getMed1() {
       return med1;
   }
   public Multimedias1 getMultimed1() {
       return multimed1;
   }
   public Outils1 getOut1() {
       return out1;
   }
   public Outils2 getOut2() {
       return out2;
   }
   public Jeux1 getJeux1() {
       return jeux1;
   }
   public Jeux2 getJeux2() {
       return jeux2;
   }
   public SocialInternet1 getSocInt1() {
       return socInt1;
   }
   public SocialInternet2 getSocInt2() {
       return socInt2;
   }

   public Appeler getAppeler() {
       return appeler;
   }
   public Urgences getUrgences() {
       return urgences;
   }
   public AppelEnCours getAppelEnCours() {
       return appelEnCours;
   }
   public DemarrageApp getDemarrageApp() {
       return demarrageApp;
   }
   public EnConstruction getEnConstruction() {
       return enConstruction;
   }
   */
   public Tutoriel getTuto() {
       return tuto;
   }

   // other getters
   public static int getFrameWidth() {
       return FRAME_WIDTH;
   }
   public static int getFrameHeight() {
       return FRAME_HEIGHT;
   }
   public JPanel getPanelChangeable() {
       return panelChangeable;
   }

   // setters
   public void setPanelChangeable(JPanel a) {
       this.panelChangeable = a;
   }
   /*
   public void switchAccueil(){
       ac1.setVisible(!ac1.isVisible());
       ac2.setVisible(!ac2.isVisible());
   }
   */
}

class Tutoriel extends JPanel {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private Body body;

   // panels
   private JPanel tout;
   private JPanel centre;
   private JPanel messageCentre1;
   private JPanel messageCentre2;

   // buttons
   private JButton ok1;
   private JButton ok2;

   private JLabel messageHaut;
   private JLabel tuto1;
   private JLabel FGauche;
   private JLabel FDroite;
   private JLabel tuto2;
   private JCheckBox tutoOff;

   //private Color fond = new Color(255, 105, 86);


   public Tutoriel(Body body) {
       super();
       this.body = body;
       buildTuto();
       setOpaque(false);
   }
   public void buildTuto() {

       this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
       tout = new JPanel();
       tout.setOpaque(false); //!!
       tout.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));
       this.add(tout);

       // tutorial announce
       messageHaut = new JLabel("TUTORIEL");
       messageHaut.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
       messageHaut.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
       messageHaut.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
       tout.add(messageHaut, BorderLayout.NORTH);

       // central panel, with the tutorial
       centre = new JPanel();
       centre.setOpaque(false);
       centre.setLayout(null);
       tout.add(centre, BorderLayout.CENTER);

       // first tutorial
       messageCentre1 = new JPanel();
       messageCentre1.setLayout(null);
       messageCentre1.setOpaque(false);
       messageCentre1.setBounds(0, 0, 250, 300);
       centre.add(messageCentre1);

       tuto1 = new JLabel("<html>POUR NAVIGUER ENTRE<br>LES DIFFÉRENTES PAGES<br>UTILISER LES FLÈCHES</html>");
       tuto1.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
       tuto1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
       tuto1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
       tuto1.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
       tuto1.setBounds(20, -10, 200, 150);
       messageCentre1.add(tuto1);

       // arrows
       FGauche = new JLabel("G");
       //!! FGauche.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/left-blue.png")));
       FGauche.setBackground(new Color(255, 153, 0));
       FGauche.setBounds(80, 150, 40, 40);
       messageCentre1.add(FGauche);

       FDroite = new JLabel("D");
       //!! FDroite.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/right-blue.png")));
       FDroite.setBackground(new Color(255, 153, 0));
       FDroite.setBounds(140, 150, 40, 40);
       messageCentre1.add(FDroite);

       // OK button, first tutorial
       ok1 = new JButton(new SelectAction(body));
       ok1.setActionCommand("tuto1");
       ok1.setText("OK");
       ok1.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
       ok1.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
       ok1.setBackground(new Color(255, 153, 0));
       ok1.setBounds(105, 230, 40, 40);
       messageCentre1.add(ok1);

       // second tutorial
       messageCentre2 = new JPanel();
       messageCentre2.setOpaque(false);
       messageCentre2.setLayout(null);
       messageCentre2.setBounds(0, 0, 250, 300);
       centre.add(messageCentre2);

       tuto2 = new JLabel("<html>POUR RETOURNER<br>A L'ACCUEIL, APPUYER<br>SUR LA TOUCHE G</html>");
       tuto2.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
       tuto2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
       tuto2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
       tuto2.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
       tuto2.setBounds(20, -10, 200, 150);
       messageCentre2.add(tuto2);

       // OK button, second tutorial
       ok2 = new JButton(new SelectAction(body));
       ok2.setActionCommand("tuto2");
       ok2.setText("OK");
       ok2.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
       ok2.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
       ok2.setBackground(new Color(255, 153, 0));
       ok2.setBounds(105, 230, 40, 40);
       messageCentre2.add(ok2);

       // visibility of tutorial panels
       //messageCentre1.setVisible(false);
       messageCentre2.setVisible(false);

       // deactivate the tutorial (and reach the main page)
       tutoOff = new JCheckBox(new SelectAction(body));
       tutoOff.setActionCommand("tutoOff");
       tutoOff.setText("NE PLUS AFFICHER AU DÉMARRAGE");
       tutoOff.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
       tout.add(tutoOff, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }
   /*
   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       g.setColor(fond);
       g.drawOval(0, 0, 50, 50);
   }
   */
   public JPanel getMessageCentre1() {
       return messageCentre1;
   }
   public JPanel getMessageCentre2() {
       return messageCentre2;
   } 

}

// !! hadd to add this to get code to compile!
class SelectAction extends AbstractAction {
   private Body body;

   public SelectAction(Body body) {
      this.body = body;
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      // TODO put some junk in here!

   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick answer, though it doesn't work. The `setOpaque(false)` was previously proposed, but didn't work either. Concerning null layout and `setBounds()`, our project has some time limits, so we cannot use the proper ways of coding our GUI, and teachers left us without anything except our brains. Hard to do directly the right choice. Thx for the advice.

Comment: @V4karian: then you're using it wrong -- `setOpaque(false)` does in fact work and for your posted code too. For example see edit to answer and try out my code.

Comment: of course, you're right. I thought I had to put it just on panels in my `Body.java` class, not in all the panels (but you said all the panels, my bad). Thank you, you saved my week-end !